# Error Starting Rails Server on New Local Machine Running Existing Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

When I run

```
./script/server
```

I get the following error message and I can't seem to find how to fix the problem. The folder is on my Desktop and is a checkout from an SVN Repository on a new machine running MacOSX 10.8.3.

```
/Users/martin/Desktop/[FOLDER NAME]/config/boot.rb:89:in `load_rubygems': undefined method `set_paths' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
from /Users/martin/Desktop/[FOLDER NAME]/config/boot.rb:52:in `load_initializer'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/[FOLDER NAME]/config/boot.rb:39:in `run'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/[FOLDER NAME]/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/[FOLDER NAME]/config/boot.rb:115:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from ./script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix/troubleshoot?

If I run `which -a ruby` I get:

```
/Users/martin/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/Users/martin/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/Users/martin/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/Users/martin/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/Users/martin/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby


rails -v

Rails 4.0.0

ruby -v

ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

Running `script/server` gives a different error

```
/Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)
from /Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle` after you checked it out?  That's how you get all the gems your app needs.  Typically, the gems themselves are not checked into your source control.  Just `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, which tell bundler what gems you need.

Comment: @Daiku - hmm, if I run `bundle` I get `Bundler::GemfileNotFound`.

Comment: Then I think you've got a grip on the problem.  Are you including `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` in your source control?  You should.

Comment: sorry for the spam, ran `bundle init` then `bundle install` and it says everything is fine, still getting the same errors though :(

Comment: Doesn't `bundle init` create a new `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?  I don't think that's what you want.  You want those files from where the app was originally checked in.  It seems to me your gems are missing.  That's what bundler is for - to specify and get the gems your app needs.

Comment: Hi, think I might be getting somewhere, I now get this error: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rspec-rails (= 2.11.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0) ruby

    rails (~> 2.3.14) ruby depends on
      actionpack (2.3.18)` but even after running `gem install actionpack` and then `rbenv rehash` I still get the same error, any ideas?